# How to check assembly is currently in use

Tags: c#, installation, vsto, .net-assembly

I am working on VSTO project. At the time of uninstall I want to detect that the assembly of vsto project is in use or not? Because I want to stop uninstall action if assembly is in use.

I am using Installer class to execute my code at the time of uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think you can reuse the following custom function I wrote for my Excel VSTO plugin project a while back. Stick it in your Installer class, and call it in `Uninstall` event handler.

```
Process[] xlProc;
public bool isExcelRunning()
    {
        try
        {
            xlProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
            if (xlProc.Length > 0)
            {
                logEvents("A running instance of Excel has been detected. The installation is stopping.");
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope it helps somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to check the specific assembly is loaded or no.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleTestAssembly
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string response;

            var exist = AssemblyExist("Camelot.SharePointConnector", out response);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(exist, Environment.NewLine, response,  Environment.NewLine));

            exist = AssemblyExist("Camelot.SharePointIntegration", out response);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(exist, Environment.NewLine, response, Environment.NewLine));

            exist = AssemblyExist("Camelot.NoExisting", out response);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(exist, Environment.NewLine, response, Environment.NewLine));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static bool AssemblyExist(string assemblyname, out string response)
        {
            try
            {
                response = QueryAssemblyInfo(assemblyname);
                return true;
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                response = e.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }

        // If assemblyName is not fully qualified, a random matching may be 
        public static String QueryAssemblyInfo(string assemblyName)
        {
            var assembyInfo = new AssemblyInfo {cchBuf = 512};
            assembyInfo.currentAssemblyPath = new String('', assembyInfo.cchBuf);

            IAssemblyCache assemblyCache;

            // Get IAssemblyCache pointer
            var hr = GacApi.CreateAssemblyCache(out assemblyCache, 0);
            if (hr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                hr = assemblyCache.QueryAssemblyInfo(1, assemblyName, ref assembyInfo);
                if (hr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr.ToInt32());
                }
             }
             else
             {
                 Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr.ToInt32());
             }

             return assembyInfo.currentAssemblyPath;
        }
    }

    internal class GacApi
    {
        [DllImport("fusion.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr CreateAssemblyCache(
            out IAssemblyCache ppAsmCache, int reserved);
    } 

    // GAC Interfaces - IAssemblyCache. As a sample, non used vtable entries 
    [ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
    Guid("e707dcde-d1cd-11d2-bab9-00c04f8eceae")]
    internal interface IAssemblyCache
    {
        int Dummy1();
        [PreserveSig()]
        IntPtr QueryAssemblyInfo(
            int flags,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            String assemblyName,
            ref AssemblyInfo assemblyInfo);

        int Dummy2();
        int Dummy3();
        int Dummy4();
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct AssemblyInfo
    {
        public int cbAssemblyInfo;
        public int assemblyFlags;
        public long assemblySizeInKB;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public String currentAssemblyPath;

        public int cchBuf;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used to following to determine if a process/assembly was running or not:

using System.Diagnostics.Process;

```
 Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName("Yourassemblyname");
```

or

```
 Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Comment: As I said, I am using VSTO project so in process name it shows EXCEL.EXE so not able to find by process name.

Comment: Take a look at the assembly class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbe1wdx9.aspx

Comment: I'm assuming you're creating a Excel plugin from your response. If your code is executing then wouldn't your assembly be in use. Confused as what you're attempting to accomplish.

Comment: I have made one excel template application installer. now at the time of uninstall, if excel template is open then I want to restrict the user from uninstall the template.